# Can nested threads throw exceptions for parent thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a `Controller` class and a `Monitor` worker thread.
The controller thread looks something like this

```
public class ControllerA {
    public void ControllerA(){
        try{
            doWork();
        }
        catch(OhNoException e){
        //catch exception
        }

    public void doWork() throws OhNoException{

      new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        //Needs to monitor resources of ControllerA, 
        //if things go wrong, it needs to throw OhNoException for its parent
        }
        }).start();

      //do work here

    }
}
```

Is such setup feasible? How do I throw exception to the outside of the thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I throw exception to the outside of the thread?

Couple ways you can do this.   You can set a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` on the thread or you can use an `ExecutorService.submit(Callable)` and use the exception that you get from the `Future.get()`.

The easiest way is to use the `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
Future<Void> future = threadPool.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
      public Void call() throws Exception {
         // can throw OhNoException here
         return null;
     }
});
// you need to shut down the pool after submitting the last task
threadPool.shutdown();
try {
   // this waits for your background task to finish, it throws if the task threw
   future.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    // this is the exception thrown by the call() which could be a OhNoException
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
     if (cause instanceof OhNoException) {
        throw (OhNoException)cause;
     } else if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
        throw (RuntimeException)cause;
     }
}
```

If you want to use the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` then you can do something like:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(...);
 final AtomicReference throwableReference = new AtomicReference<Throwable>();
 thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
     public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
         throwableReference.set(e);
     }
 });
 thread.start();
 thread.join();
 Throwable throwable = throwableReference.get();
 if (throwable != null) {
     if (throwable instanceof OhNoException) {
        throw (OhNoException)throwable;
     } else if (throwable instanceof RuntimeException) {
        throw (RuntimeException)throwable;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Wow never seen anything like this before. I wonder if the Future thread would constantly run in the background or would it only run once and shutdown? and when does it begin?

Comment: The future thread begins immediately when it is submitted.  It runs in the background once and then stops when the `call()` method returns @Yonk.

Comment: why would you need a AtomicReference in your second example, isnt there a memory barrier on thread.join (see http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html)? so all writes should be visible

Comment: You don't really need an atomic mutable class @leozilla but it's a convenient class to use to pass back the throwable to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Runnable interface cannot throw checked exceptions or return values. In The Callable interface you can call any worker method that return values or throws exceptions. The main tasks of the monitor would be

1. To declare and initialize the future with the callable instance.
2. A getResult() method that can have a `return future.get();` statement and should declare any checked exceptions in its throws clause for it to be handled by the calling code. In this way we dont have to return a null.

Comment: yes Runnable cannot throw checked exceptions only RuntimeException's or Errors.I just edited it.